# Change embedded google maps location with HTML links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage with a google-maps embedded in it.

Currently the location is hard coded into the script and goes to Mountain View. which looks like this:

```html
      <iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?zoom=12&center=37.3861,-122.0839&.......>
```

I want to keep mountain view as the default location but I also have 5 links (Paris - Beijing - London etc...) and I want to be able to change the location of the embedded map by clicking on the links

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: you can't change the source of an iframe you'll just have to create different maps for each one

Comment: thanks. If I create different maps how can i switch between the frames?

Comment: Just show a new page on click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('button').each(function(i, btn) {
  $(btn).click(function() {
    $('iframe').attr('src', 'https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyDn5TU07R040YBRD-9ePpM8Noh-Z1NNVyw&q=' + $(btn).data('lat') + ',' + $(btn).data('long'));
    // this api key will expire. It's just for this example.
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button typeof="button" data-lat="37.9758438" data-long="23.7454209">Greece</button>
<button typeof="button" data-lat="48.8588589" data-long="2.3470599">Paris</button>
<button typeof="button" data-lat="37.4038194" data-long="-122.081267">Mountain View</button>

<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyDn5TU07R040YBRD-9ePpM8Noh-Z1NNVyw&q=37.4038194,-122.081267"></iframe>
```

This is an example. There are many ways to achieve the same result. Note that I used jQuery for element manipulation.