# Change embedded google map location based on selection

Tags: jquery, google-maps, onclick

Thanks to a previous question from another user I have been able to set up an embedded map on my webpage and created some buttons.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button typeof="button" data-lat="37.9758438" data-long="23.7454209">Na Fianna</button>
<button typeof="button" data-lat="48.8588589" data-long="2.3470599">St. Pauls</button>
<button typeof="button" data-lat="37.4038194" data-long="-122.081267">Kevins</button>

<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d9521.05146600762!2d-6.2630277!3d53.374346!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x72398e1c9e377ac0!2sCLG+Na+Fianna!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sie!4v1448021350769" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

However I don't know how to get the embedded map to change location based on which button is selected.

Comment: So to expand I would like the iframe to update with the coordinates in the button that is selected and show that location on the embedded google map on my page.

Comment: Your current `<iframe>` has a "place" selected.  Do you want that for the other coordinates?  Or just a map centered on those coordinates?

Comment: Once someone clicks on one of the buttons the map should change to that specific place. I haven't actually used the specific coordinates in the code that I want yet as I assume I can change those later as appropriate.

Comment: related question: [changing iframe source with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930315/changing-iframe-source-with-jquery)

Comment: This is what I am trying to emulate but I am not sure where each piece of code should be placed in ruby on rails.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633278/change-embedded-google-maps-location-with-html-links

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the [documentation for the embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#view_mode):

> The following URL parameter is required:
>
> **center** defines the center of the map window, and accepts a latitude and a longitude as comma-separated values (-33.8569,151.2152).
>   Optional parameters
>
> The following optional parameters can be used with any of the map modes listed above.
>
> **zoom** sets the initial zoom level of the map. Accepted values range from 0 (the whole world) to 21 (individual buildings). The upper limit can vary depending on the map data available at the selected location.
>   **maptype** can be either roadmap (the default) or satellite, and defines the type of map tiles to load.

One option:

```
$(function() {
  $('button').each(function(i, btn) {
    $(btn).click(function() {
      var el = $(this)[0];
      var urlbeg="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?key=yourApiKey&center=";
      var urlend="&zoom=18&maptype=roadmap";
      var lat=el.dataset.lat;
      var lng=el.dataset.long;
      $("iframe").attr("src",urlbeg+lat+","+lng+urlend);
    });
  });
});
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/example_embedded_map_changeable.html)

Answer (score 0):

add one of the following parameters at the end of your map URL to change the map location:

1. `&origin=lat,lang`
2. `&center=lat,lang`
3. `&ll=lat,lang`